# Return a list with the 5 words that have the smaller distance from the levenstein distance

Tags: python

I have a function named distance who is associated to the levenstein distance. I want to make the distance between that word and every word in the .txt file.
I don't know how do I make that function to return a list with the 5 words that have the smaller distance.
If someone can help solve this problem, thank you very much.

```
suggest('filename.txt', 'promeessa', distance)
```

I will put my levenstein distance code below

```
def distance(word1, word2):
    mat = [[0 for j in range(len(word1)+1)] for i in range(len(word2)+1)]

    for i in range(len(word2)+1):
        mat[i][0] = i

    for j in range(len(word1)+1):
        mat[0][j] = j

    for i in range(1, len(word2)+1):
        for j in range(1, len(word1)+1):
            if word1[j-1] == word2[i-1]:
                mat[i][j] = mat[i-1][j-1]
            else:
                mat[i][j] = min([mat[i-1][j], mat[i][j-1], mat[i-1][j-1]]) + 1

    return mat[len(word2)][len(word1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the list using the distance as a key then take the first 5:

```py
def suggest(filename, target_word, distance_func):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
    words = content.split()
    return sorted(words, key=lambda word: distance_func(word, target_word))[:5]
```